# How to force fullscreen ListView for jQuery Mobile select control

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile-application

I'm using PhoneGap 2.5.0 with jQuery Mobile 1.3.0.  I want to have a select control which uses a custom (i.e. not native) menu when a user clicks it.  That works fine, but the jQuery Mobile docs indicate that:

> When it has too many options to show on the device's screen, the
>   framework will automatically create a new "page" populated with a
>   standard listview for the options. This allows us to use the native
>   scrolling included on the device for moving through a long list.

This also works fine, when you have more options than whatever unpublished number is the limit.  What I'd like to know is if there is a way to force the custom menu to open in this mode, regardless of the number of options in the select.

The API docs don't list any option or method that would seem to fit this purpose, so I'm expecting that the answer to my question is that it isn't possible, but I just thought I'd ask.

Comment: how can we stops to create new page if you have solution then please comment.